# In php how can i wrap a span tag around the last character?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Hi i need to wrap the last letter of a string in a span tag, how can i do this in php?

for instance:

```
$string = 'Get on the roller coaster';
```

Should be output:

```
'Get on the roller coaste<span>r</span>'
```

Comment: O_o Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I want to colour the last letter differently but don't have control of the html as its dynamically created by wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

find

```
(.)$
```

replace with

```
<span>\1</span>
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/bY8kX0

like this in php:

```
<?php
$string = 'Get on the roller coaster';
echo preg_replace('/(.)$/', '<span>\1</span>', $string);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex:

```
(.)$
```

And replace it with:

```
<span>\1</span>
```

`.` means a character and `$` means the end and `()` is used to group the character so it can be used.

So the regex says: Match the last character.

I think this is a overkill and would have given a native php answer but, I don't know php :)

Thanks sshashank124 for the grouping tip!

Comment: php uses `\1` instead

Comment: You can use `$1` or `\1` in a replacement pattern, it's the same in PHP.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, thanks mate. So I shouldn't have trouble using `$1` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll probably get bashed for inefficiency but here is an alternative :)

```
// your string :)
$string = 'Get on the roller coaster';

// count the chars of your string, not the bytes ;)
$stringLength = mb_strlen($string);

// a string's characters can be accessed in array form IF it is an actual string and not an INT or w/e
// echo $string[0] would produce the letter 'G'
// so we want the last character, right-o!
$wrapped = '<span>'.$string[($stringLength - 1)].'</span>';

// mb_substr() the old string and give it that <span>-wrapped char
$newString = mb_substr($string, 0, -1).$wrapped;

// and presto!
// $newString is now === Get on the roller coaste<span>r</span>
```

Comment: thats way better, regex is more heavy, but use `mb_substr($string, 0, -1)`

Comment: @Eun Thanks! I'm only 3 cups of coffee deep and it's almost 10am so I think I'll grab another one. That was a big ol' DURRR moment :)

Comment: You can even get rid of the `$stringLength`

Comment: So is it better for me to use this example as opposed to aelor's? Is regex slower?

Comment: yeah that would be cool. I can't get this example to work though getting undefined errors

Comment: After running `100,000` iterations of each I have found that **mine is ~4-5% faster** which equates to about `0.04` seconds for `100k` iterations on my AMD Phenom II x2 B53 2.8GHz CPU. Mine was `0.78` and aelors took `0.82` In conclusion: the performance difference is negligible unless your equation of (several thousand visitors) * (number of times this code is activated) is large enough.

Comment: Thanks, as i cannot get this to run without error i'll use the regex.

Comment: If you wanted to copy+paste the exact error(s) then I might be able to help you work through them. I doubt the script is die-ing and only outputting `Undefined Errors` =)